# How to put the type of document in the first page

Tags: formatting

Good evening everyone. I have the following code in Latex.

```
\documentclass[12pt, fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[load=accepted]{siunitx}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{anyfontsize}
 \usepackage{t1enc}

 \usepackage{titlesec}

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


 \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields



   \usepackage{titling}
    \setlength\droptitle{-5cm}
    \renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\raisebox{-0.35\height}
     {\hspace*{-3cm}\includegraphics[width=4cm]{TUC}}\quad\sffamily    \begin{tabular}{l}  {\selectlanguage{english}{TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY OF CRETE}}\\   [3ex]{\selectlanguage{english} SCHOOL OF PRODUCTION ENGINEERING AND   MANAGEMENT}\end{tabular}\vskip 24ex}

   \renewcommand\maketitlehookb{\vskip 8ex}
   \renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vfill}


  \selectlanguage{english}

  \title{Vehicle path and traffic flow optimization via  lane changing of automated or semi-automated vehicles on motorways}
 \author{Georgantas Antonios}





  \date{Chania 2016}
  \begin{document}
   \selectlanguage{english}
   \maketitle
   \end{document}
```

What I want to do, is to add two rows after the name the "Diploma Thesis", but I can't figure out how. Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Your document is incomplete and as such not compilable

Comment: It is just a fragment. The document is complete now.

Comment: Your posting is not all that clear. Please clarify what you mean by `to add two rows after the name the "Diploma Thesis"`. Have you tried changing the `\author` directive to `\author{Georgantas Antonios\\ \\ Diploma Thesis}`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you want the extra lines.  Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[load=accepted]{siunitx}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{anyfontsize}
 \usepackage{t1enc}

 \usepackage{titlesec}

 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


 \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields



   \usepackage{titling}
    \setlength\droptitle{-5cm}
    \renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\raisebox{-0.35\height}
     {\hspace*{-3cm}\includegraphics[width=4cm]{TUC}}\quad\sffamily    \begin{tabular}{l}  {\selectlanguage{english}{TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY OF CRETE}}\\   [3ex]{\selectlanguage{english} SCHOOL OF PRODUCTION ENGINEERING AND   MANAGEMENT}\end{tabular}\vskip 24ex}

   \renewcommand\maketitlehookb{\vskip 8ex}
   \renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vfill}


  \selectlanguage{english}

  \title{Vehicle path and traffic flow optimization via  lane changing of automated or semi-automated vehicles on motorways}
 \author{Georgantas Antonios\\Diploma\\Thesis}





  \date{Chania 2016}
  \begin{document}
   \selectlanguage{english}
   \maketitle
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Yes exactly guys, I hadn't thought to put it together with the author. Thanks